# Problem about Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

My question is as follows：

Let $\mathscr{X}$ be a real Banach space,and let $f$ be a non-zero real linear functional on $\mathscr{X}$,show that there not be open ball $B(x_0,\delta)$ such that $f(x_0)$ is the maximum or minimum in $B(x_0,\delta)$ of $f(x)$.

Please help me and give me details!

Thank you!

Comment: What are your ideas on the problem ? Any specific attempts ?

Comment: I have no idea how to solve it !

Comment: Try writing down what a linear functional is. What does $X$ being a Banach space mean ? What about subsets of a Banach space ?

Comment: Of course, I am familiar with these fundamental concepts.

Comment: Combine them now with the facts of an open ball and extrema of a function and it will lead you to the proof!

Comment: OK, I will try it ,thank you !

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Since $f$ is nonzero, there is a unit vector $v$ such that $f(v)>0$. 
Then consider $f(x_0-\varepsilon v)$ and $f(x_0+\varepsilon v)$ with $0<\varepsilon<\delta$.

Comment: what is the operation on $f(x_0-\varepsilon v)$ and $f(x_0+\varepsilon v)$ you want ? I can not figure out your mean.

Comment: Use *linearity* of $f$ and try to conclude that $f(x_0)$ is not minimum/maximum.